# Scaling that preserves the ratio between any two values

Tags: functions, ratio

Is there a function $f$ such that for all $x$ (on a **bounded** domain):

1. $f(x) \in [a,b]$
2. $r \times f(x) = f(rx)$

If it makes things easier, we can assume that $\forall x: x \geq 0$. Though a more general solution would be nice.

P.S. I figure that it may be impossible to find such a scaling under some circumstances. For example, a scaling that maps $x_{max}$ to $a$ and $x_{min}$ to $b$ obviously needs $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{x_{max}}{x_{min}}$

Comment: Since $x$ is bounded, $r$ should also be bounded

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking, the answer is that $f(x)=kx$ for some constant $k$.

Comment: If you mean the 2nd equation to hold for all $r$, then clearly $f(x) = f(x\cdot 1) = xf(1)$. Setting $k = f(1)$, you get $f(x) = kx$ as the only possible answer. On the other hand, if $r$ is a fixed constant, then there are uncountably many such functions, but most are not continuous.

Comment: I agree with you. After some thoughts, I came to the same conclusion that $f(x)=kx$ may be the only viable solution. $f(x)=kx$ is linear. At first, I thought there might be some non-linear function that maintains the ratio (for any $r$), at least approximately.